# scipy.misc.derivative for uneven space points

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, anaconda

I want to calculate the second derivative for each point (except the first and last one) in a points set. This points set has a data type of dictionary, which is like `points = {x1:y1, x2:y2, ... xn:yn}` where all the `x` are positive integers but it is in uneven spacing, e.g., `x1=1, x2=2, x3=3, x4=5, x5=7` the `x` numbers are not increased linearly and the gap could be random, i.e., `x_{i+1} - x_{i}` could be any positive integer.

For this dictionary of points, I want to get second derivative for each point, so I did the coding like:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import derivative
def wrapper(x):
    return np.array([points[int(i)] for i in x])
y_d2 = derivative(wrapper, np.array(list(points.keys()))[1:-1], dx=1.0, n=2)
```

In this case, I will get `KeyError: 4` at `return np.array([points[int(i)] for i in x])`. It is becasue the `x=4` does not exist in the points dictionary so that it has a key error. How could I use scipy.misc.derivative for this situation? How to set the `dx` parameter (spacing) for `scipy.misc.derivative`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to use scipy.misc.derivative? Because it is very easy to calculate second derivatives without

Let's say you have your data as a dictionary:

```
points = {1:2, 2:2, 4:4, 5:5}
```

Then all you do is first get them into x,y lists:

```
x,y = list(points.keys()), list(points.values())
```

and then calculate derivs using numpy diff

```
dy_dx = np.diff(y)/np.diff(x)
d2y_dx2 = np.diff(dy_dx)/np.diff(x[:-1])
```

output for `d2y_dx2` is

```
array([1., 0.])
```

as expected.

Of course there are more sophisticated versions of this if you want to use higher-accuracy formulas for derivatives, eg you can create a spline from your x,y and calculate derivatives of the spline. But I would start with the basic scheme above unless there are compelling reasons for anything else